# File.Create("Name.txt").Dispose() Working on computer, but not on Android

Tags: c#, android, file, save

As I mentioned, I tried deleting save files and runging game on a computer and it works perfectly.  But on Android it either doesn't create a file, or it does create it but doesn't write anything in it.

Here is my code for `SaveFileManagement`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class onAppStart : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text moneyText;

    void Start () {
        if (!File.Exists("doubleMoney.txt"))
        {
            File.Create("doubleMoney").Dispose();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("doubleMoney.txt", "0");
        }

        if (!File.Exists("money.txt"))
        {
            File.Create("money").Dispose();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("money.txt", "2.5");
            double doubleMoney = Convert.ToDouble(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("money.txt"));
            float money = ToSingle(doubleMoney);
            moneyText.text = money.ToString() + "$";
        }
        else
        {
            double doubleMoney = Convert.ToDouble(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("money.txt"));
            float money = ToSingle(doubleMoney);
            moneyText.text = money.ToString() + "$";
        }
    }

    public static float ToSingle(double value)
    {
        return (float)value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create "doubleMoney", but write to/check existence of "doubleMoney.txt".  Fix your filenames to be consistent.

Comment: Nooo, It works on computer, btw there is code if (!File.Exists("money.txt")) and it checks for that file and creates money.txt... Just problems with android,  I don't know, maybe android doesn't support that kind of filemaking code... Do I need different code?

Comment: No, your code checks if "money.txt" exists and if not creates the file "money".

Comment: Okej, I have fixed that, haven't even noticed, even tho it has been creating this random files with no extension and I just left it, thanks for that, but it still doesn't work on android, like file is not being created at all or is not being write... Is there any other way for saving strings to file in more "Android-ish" way?